# Multiple AND conditions in a mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
+------------+--------------------+----------+-------------+
| id_product | name               | id_brand | id_category |
+------------+--------------------+----------+-------------+
|          1 | Nokia E55          |      120 |           1 |
|          2 | Nokia E75 (Red)    |      101 |           1 |
|          3 | Nokia N86          |      105 |           2 |
|          4 | Nokia 6700 Classic |      110 |           2 |
|          5 | Nokia 6260 Slide   |      120 |           1 |
+------------+--------------------+----------+-------------+
```

What I want to do is, I have the following data

```
id_category = 1,2
id_brand = 110,105
```

Now I want the following products

```
Nokia 6700 Classic
Nokia N86
```

only

because there is no brand (110,105) in id_category 1.......

Comment: what did you want, i can't understand pls. if you want the following sql query only.. i can't believe it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this:

```
WHERE id_category IN (1,2) AND id_brand IN (110,105)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WHERE id_category in (1,2) and  id_brand in (110,105)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select name from tbl_name where id_category in (1,2) and id_brand in (110,105);
```